# Tkinter grid not working

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create a window, and content all in center, but I don't know how should I do, please help me.

```
def about_window():
    win_about = tk.Toplevel(win)
    win_about.geometry("340x500")
    win_about.title("About Us")
    win_about.resizable(0,0)
    win_about.iconbitmap(r'C:/Users/810810/Desktop/python/eslogo.ico')
    frame = tk.Frame(win_about)
    frame.grid(row=0, column=2)

    img_png = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'est.gif')
    label = tk.Label(frame, image = img_png)
    label.img_png = img_png
    label.grid(row=0, column=1)

    Message = 'Version: 1.0'
    mess = tk.Label(frame, text=Message)
    mess.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

Comment: Explain about your problem clearly

Comment: when I change "mess.grid(row=1, column=0)" to "mess.grid(row=1, column=1)", the label and mess are in the left place, but I hope in the center.

Comment: There should be something on the 0th column....so place any logo or anything on (0,0)

Comment: I tried place something in (0,0), but still have same result.

Comment: Remove that frame and use win_about everywhere

Answer (score 1):

I've also had a lot of problems with `tkinter grid` and prefer to use `tkinter place`.

Below I edited your code to use `place` instead of `grid`. `anchor` refers to the anchor point of the object you are moving around, `relx` refers to the relative x position as a percentage of the frame it's in (`.5` meaning halfway through the frame), and `rely` refers to the y position in the frame from 0-1.

```
import tkinter as tk

win_about = tk.Tk()
win_about.geometry("340x500")
win_about.title("About Us")
win_about.resizable(0,0)

label = tk.Label(win_about, text="img_png", fg="black")
label.place(anchor='center', relx =.5, rely=.3)

mess = tk.Label(win_about, text='Version: 1.0', font=12)
mess.place(anchor='center', relx=.5, rely=.7)

win_about.mainloop()
```

Comment: sorry, I tried your method, but it don't show anything

Comment: forgot to pack the frame. Try now

Comment: Have same result.

Comment: Ok I simplified it so you can literally just copy paste that now

Answer (score 0):

this should work (It worked on my ubuntu 16 with python 2.7)

it opens 2 windows ,is that wanted or unwanted ?

it displays an image in the center and your text below.

it works by adding "                         " strings, just like neeraj nair suggested. (he suggested placing anything to adjust layout.)

(@ Elvis Fan: i know you use windows, but it should work for windows too.)

```
import Tkinter as tk
def about_window():
    win_about = tk.Toplevel()
    win_about.geometry("340x500")
    win_about.title("About Us")
    win_about.resizable(0,0)
    frame = tk.Frame(win_about)
    frame.grid(row=0, column=2)
    for i in range(0,12):
        Message = " "
        mess = tk.Label(frame, text=Message)
        mess.grid(row=i, column=0)
    img_png = tk.PhotoImage(file = 'gbsnode.png')
    label = tk.Label(frame, image = img_png)
    label.img_png = img_png
    label.grid(row=21, column=2)
    Message = '                                '
    mess = tk.Label(frame, text=Message)
    mess.grid(row=23, column=1)
    Message = 'Version 1'
    mess = tk.Label(frame, text=Message)
    mess.grid(row=24, column=2)
    frame.mainloop()
about_window()
while True:
    pass
```